# Capybara - assert_selector("tr#1234") doesn't work, but find_by_id(1234) does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

What are possible reasons that doing `page.find_by_id(id)` works, but doing `page.assert_selector("tr##{id}") returns a`Capybara::ElementNotFound`?

For background, I am using the [Poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist) driver for [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara).

I have HTML that is structured like so:

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="1234">
    <td>Rico Jones</td>
    <td><a href="/price_requests/5678">Price Request</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2345">
    <td>Rico Jones</td>
    <td><a href=/price_requests/6789">Price Request</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have confirmed that my HTML is coming out as expected by using the `page.driver.debug` feature of Poltergeist and looking at the actual HTML generated by the test.

When I put something like this in my tests, I get a `Capybara::Poltergeist::InvalidSelector` error with the message `The browser raised a syntax error while trying to evaluate the selector`.

```
lead = Lead.first
assert_selector "tr##{lead.id}"
```

I also get an error when doing this:

```
lead = Lead.first
within "tr##{lead.id}" do
  click_on "Price Request"
end
```

However, using `find_by_id` works:

```
lead = Lead.first
find_by_id(lead.id).click_on("Price Request")
```

Based on my understanding of Capybara, this shouldn't be the case. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might be seeing inconsistencies because ID's should not begin with numbers: http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/.

Comment: You are correct. Changing the `id` to start with a letter fixed my issue. I was actually getting a `Capybara::Poltergeist::InvalidSelector: The browser raised a syntax error while trying to evaluate the selector` error, which should have tipped me off. Wanna create an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because ID's should not begin with numbers, as [shown here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id).

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").